# Python: How do you determine if a list of unordered tuples as dictionary values is IN another dictionaries.values()?

Tags: python, dictionary

When I run this code I would expect it to return keys 1 and 3 from dict1 but it only returns the first key. I need it to return all matches per key/value iteration from dict1. Thanks for help!

```
dict1={1:[(3.5, 7.8),(1.5, 2.5)], 2: [(6.3, 8.5)], 3:[(3.4,5.6)]}
dict2={1:[(1.5, 2.5), (3.5, 7.8)], 2: [(2.3, 1.5)], 3:[(3.4,5.6)]}

for k, v in dict1.items():
    if set(v).issubset(set(next(iter(dict2.values())))):
       print(k, v)
```

Comment: `set(next(iter(dict2.values())` is always the same, it is a set containing whatever the first value of the dictionary. You can guarantee that it will be `{(1.5,2.5),(3.5,7.8)}` in Python 3.7

Comment: Do you actually need a subset test here, or just an `==` test? Since all of the tuples in your examples are 2-tuples, there's no difference between them; if that's true in your real code, you could simplify things…

Comment: I need the values to be equal regardless of what order the tuple items in each list are in i.e. key 1 in both dictionaries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is pretty obvious:

```
for k, v in dict1.items():
    if set(v).issubset(set(next(iter(dict2.values())))):
       print(k, v)
```

That `next(iter(dict2.values())` just gets the first value. If you want to iterate all of the values, you have to actually iterate all of the values:

```
for k, v in dict1.items():
    for v2 in dict2.values():
        if set(v).issubset(set(v2)):
           print(k, v)
           break
```

If you really want to condense that back into a one-liner after you've got it working, you can:

```
for k, v in dict1.items():
    if any(set(v).issubset(set(v2)) for v2 in dict2.values()):
       print(k, v)
```

Either way, you probably want to take the `set(v)` outside the loop, though:

```
for k, v in dict1.items():
    v = set(v)
    if any(v.issubset(set(v2)) for v2 in dict2.values()):
       print(k, v)
```

---

While we're at it, do you really even need a subset test? All of your example tuples are 2-tuples, so `v.issubset(v2)` is true iff `v == v2`. Which is much simpler to test for:

```
for k, v in dict1.items():
    v = set(v)
    if any(v == set(v2) for v2 in dict2.values()):
       print(k, v)
```

Or:

```
for k, v in dict1.items():
    if set(v) in {set(v2) for v2 in dict2.values()}:
       print(k, v)
```

Or:

```
for k, v in dict1.items():
    if set(v) in map(set, dict2.values()):
       print(k, v)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> dict2_items = map(set, dict2.values())
>>> [(k,v) for k, v in dict1.items() if set(v) in dict2_items]
[(1, [(3.5, 7.8), (1.5, 2.5)]), (3, [(3.4, 5.6)])]
```